# Do wooden storm windows need weep holes?

Tags: windows, weatherstripping, weep-hole

I have read about the importance of weep holes with aluminum storm windows, but we have several old wooden storms in our house.  Do those naturally drain because they're not airtight, or is some kind of weep hole needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will see weep holes in aluminum storm windows when the frame is projecting from the exterior wall and has a "lipped" edge. The weep holes allow drainage that otherwise would not occur because of the lipped frame edge. Wooden storm windows are usually hinged and set flush with the frame. The frame bottom is normally beveled so as to shed water away from the interior. If you have weather-stripping installed on the storm windows that creates a good seal it may be wise to modify it if you see water entering past the storm window.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That makes a lot of sense.  All the articles I found about weep holes didn't really explain what's happening with the lip.  My wooden storms are flush as you expected.  Incidentally, I can't seem to find weep holes inside or out of our aluminum storms though.  I assume they're not quite as important if we have eaves?

Comment: Actually, I forgot.  Water can come from condensation even if the window isn't directly exposed to water.

Comment: weep holes are usually at the bottom outside edge, but can also be found at the sides of he frame (rarely). Also, depending on the frame type, may not be necessary due to the configuration of the frame.

Comment: Any guidance on how I can tell the case where it wouldn't be needed? Pour a cup or two of water in sill?

Comment: That's a good way to check. It also would show a worst case scenario from water penetration. If water is retained in the sill and you decide to open weep holes keep them away from the edge where water may find a route past the frame joint.